# Error when reclassifying arcgis data that was interpolated

Tags: python, geospatial, arcgis

I am getting an "ExecuteError: ERROR 000582: Error occurred during execution." while running my code. What I am trying to do is converting earthquake data ive parsed from the USGS into a layer, interpolating it and then reclassifying the values in correlation with the Mercalli scale of earthquake measurement.

My python code is here.

```
def geoprocessing(event, ut):
data=folder+ '\\' + event + '.txt'
layer=event+'e_layer'
idwOutput=workspace+'\idw_'+event
arcpy.MakeXYEventLayer_management(data,"longitude","latitude", layer,spRef)
Print_Message("Event ["+ event + "] and mask setup completed")
arcpy.gp.Idw_sa(layer, "PGA",idwOutput, "", "2", "VARIABLE 12", "")
Print_Message("Interpolation done!")

# Reclassifying shake acceleration based on the 
idwReclass= Reclassify(idwOutput, "Value", RemapRange([[0,0.17,1],[0.17,1.39,2],[1.39,1.40,3],[1.40,3.89,4],[3.89,9.19,5],[9.19,17.99,6],[17.99,33.99,7],[3.99,64.99,8],[64.99,123.99,9],[123.99,500,10]]), "DATA")
Print_Message("Reclassification of shake acceleration done!")
```

And here's the Error returned from running python code.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):


File "C:/Users/Vignesh/Desktop/Final Project Scripts/1_6.py", line 294, in <module>
    process_years(int(Start_Year),int(End_Year),State_ab)
  File "C:/Users/Vignesh/Desktop/Final Project Scripts/1_6.py", line 164, in process_years
    if (main_process(values[1], state)):
  File "C:/Users/Vignesh/Desktop/Final Project Scripts/1_6.py", line 192, in main_process
    if (geoprocessing(event, state)):
  File "C:/Users/Vignesh/Desktop/Final Project Scripts/1_6.py", line 213, in geoprocessing
    idwReclass= Reclassify(idwOutput, "Value", RemapRange([[0,0.17,1],[0.17,1.39,2],[1.39,1.40,3],[1.40,3.89,4],[3.89,9.19,5],[9.19,17.99,6],[17.99,33.99,7],[3.99,64.99,8],[64.99,123.99,9],[123.99,500,10]]), "DATA")
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.3\ArcPy\arcpy\sa\Functions.py", line 5603, in Reclassify
    missing_values)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.3\ArcPy\arcpy\sa\Utils.py", line 53, in swapper
    result = wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.3\ArcPy\arcpy\sa\Functions.py", line 5597, in Wrapper
    missing_values)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.3\ArcPy\arcpy\geoprocessing\_base.py", line 504, in <lambda>
    return lambda *args: val(*gp_fixargs(args, True))
ExecuteError: ERROR 000582: Error occurred during execution.
```

I am uncertain why I am getting this error. Can some one help me out?

Comment: Normally we prefer that you post the code that you suspect may be problematic.

Comment: @ouflak  Oh, the account is new and stackoverflow didn't let me directly post the image.... all sorted now thanks to an edit.

Comment: Try to use the coding tags to post suspect code instead of images which can be hard to read on different viewers.